# Problem is using Angular `renderer ` for creating radio buttons

Tags: angular

I was trying to create some radio buttons dynamically using `renderer` in angular.
Can someone help me and explain how I can create radiobutton using `renderer` dynamically.
I have a simple code snippet like this:

**Component.ts**

```js
const p: HTMLParagraphElement = this.renderer.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "add new";
this.renderer.appendChild(this.div.nativeElement, p);
```

**Component.html**

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-{{i}}" id="radio-{{i}}-{{j}}" (click)="questionBuild(consult)" />
<label class="sr-text" for="radio-{{i}}-{{j}}">{{consult.value.text}}</label>
<ng-container *ngIf="consult.value.questions">
    <div #questions></div>
</ng-container>
```

Based on my `#question` state I want to add further radio buttons if condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to generate an option object as follows in your `Component.ts` and base the different conditions you change that which causes in rendering different number of radio button in your `Template`:

> Component.ts

```js
export class Question {
    Id: number;
    value: string;
}
let Options: Question [] = [];
private QuestionNum = 0;

questionBuild(consult) => {
  this.QuestionNum++;
  let question = new Question();
  question.id = this.QuestionNum;
  question.value = consult.value.questions;
  this.Options.push(question);
}
```

> Component.html

```html
<input type="radio" name="firstRadio" id="0" (click)="questionBuild(consult)" />
<label class="sr-text" for="radio-{{i}}-{{j}}">{{consult.value.text}}</label>
<ng-container *ngIf="options.lenght > 0">
    <span *ngFor="let option of options">
        <input type="radio" name="option.value" id="option.id" (click)="questionBuild(consult)" />
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: but what if I have more question within questionbuild  the inner one how can i append the span then how can i handle that

Comment: Use different option objects based on your questions can be a good way.

Comment: did get what you mean ? plz elaborate should i share a json format here of my data for reference

Comment: Yes, it's better to define an interface or model for your radio options